# No Signature help for R methods in Sublime Text

Tags: r, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime Text (Build 4126) on a MacBook Pro (running Monterey 12.2.1) with the R-IDE package.  I installed it as described at:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/R-IDE

i.e., in R: install.packages("languageserver"); then in Sublime: install R-IDE, LSP, and LSP-R from Package Control.

Items under the R-IDE menu work as expected, syntax highlighting works, and the hover feature shows references to other occurrences of the item under the cursor.  However, signature help doesn't work.  This worked (most of the time) under R-Box (both written by randy3k).  I've tried playing with settings files, but really don't know what I'm doing.  I suspect this is probably a *languageserver* issue (https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver), but I'm just fumbling around.

Any suggestions on how to get signature help working for R in Sublime Text?  Is anyone else not able to get it working?

Comment: Have you looked at the configuration options for LSP-R? `Preferences > Package Settings > LSP > Servers > LSP-R`

Comment: @MattDMo - I have, but the only things I found to try were setting:  "r.lsp.rich_documentation": true, "languageId": "r",
and "enabled": true .  These didn't change anything.  I also looked at *languageserver* at [link](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver/blob/master/R/capabilities.R).  Here there is a reference to SignatureHelpOptions, which includes triggerCharacters.  Because of this reference, I tend to think the issue requires doing something with *languageserver*.